# get-winevent: cannot filter specific field FailureReason %%2313

Tags: powershell, get-winevent

I'm poking around with get-winevent for the event 4625 because i need the failure-reason, which is in a xml field of the event.

the first thing i tried is to print out all fields hoping, the failure reason is available somewhere in the data-path of the xml, with no success.

i did not found a way to query the statuscode %%2313 to something with powershell to get the readable text.

the last thing i did is filtering the specific event and write the statusmessage myself in a custom field of my export file.

I used this code to accomplish that:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Path="c:\temp\test.evtx";} -ErrorAction     SilentlyContinue |
    Where-Object {($_.id -eq "4625" -and $_.properties[9].value -in "%%    2313")}|ForEach-Object{
$SelectorStrings = [string[]]@(
            'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="TargetUserName"]',
            'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="TargetDomainName"]',
            'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="WorkstationName"]',
            'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="IpAddress"]',
            'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="IpPort"]',
            'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="LogonType"]',
            'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="FailureReason"]',
            'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="Remark"]'
            )
           $PropertySelector = [System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogPropertySelector]::new($SelectorStrings)

            $TargetUserName,$TargetDomainName,$WorkstationName,$IpAddress,$IpPort,$LogonType,$FailureReason,$Remark = $_.GetPropertyValues($PropertySelector)
            $Remark ="Unbekannter Benutzername oder ungültiges Kennwort."
            #Create the PSCustomObject from the given Fieldnames
            [PSCustomObject]@{
            TimeCreated  = $_.TimeCreated
            Id           = $_.Id
            UserName     = $TargetUserName
            Domain       = $TargetDomainName
            WorkstationName = $WorkstationName
            IPAddress    = $IpAddress
            Port         = $IpPort
            LogonType    = $LogonType
            Message      = ($_.Message).split(".")[0]
            Remark       = $Remark
            FailureReason =$FailureReason
            }      
        }|Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Force -Encoding UTF8 -Path 'c:\temp\failurereason.csv'
```

but: it seams i cannot filter for %%2313 as property value. no idea why. Even with quotation marks or something, dont get any event out.

Comment: `-in` is an array operator and might not behave as you expect but should still sort of work assuming you get the text _exactly_ right. Using `-eq` instead would make more sense if the text is exact. You could always try `-like "*%%2313*"` or even regex depending. Your code and example do not match. There is white space in the code. When you print out `$_.properties[9].value` what does it look like?

Comment: Hello, the whitespaces are incorrect, the line should look like $_.properties[9].value -in "%%2313". echoing the $_.properties[9].value gives me a wrong value. Thanks for helping me on the train, i simply queried the wrong properties-field. it should be properties[8] and works like a charm. Really really thank you